# How to add an error message in my unity project when the asset bundle is of wrong format?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, virtual-reality, hololens, assetbundle

I want to show the error message when the asset bundle uploaded is of wrong format. How can it be done in my unity project?

Comment: `Debug.LogError("message")` or what do you mean? Or `try { ... } catch(Exception e) { Debug.Log(e.ToString()); }`?

Comment: Is there any other ways apart from try and catch?

Comment: Well I still don't know what you are talking about exactly .. so I don't know

Comment: Let me give an example, so when I upload an android asset bundle instead of iOS bundle, I must be able to show an error message telling that the uploaded bundle is not as expected.

Comment: @swathi what do you mean by 'upload'.  Try catch sounds like the correct approach for handling bad formats, it has the added benefit that it lets you handle other issues too (corrupted files, connection dropouts etc..) so you should probably be using try catch anyway.